# Eight queens puzzle - diagonal patterns

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and started learning Python recently. While practicing the use of Loop and working on the eight queens puzzle, I'm having difficulty with finding a way to check on diagonal attacks. I'm hoping you can help me with solving diagonal patterns. Thank you!

Here's what I have written so far:

```
A = []
for I in range(0,8):
    A.append([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
for I in range(1,8):
    Valid = False
    while not Valid:
        S = input('Enter position'+ str(I) +' : ')
        X = int(S[0])-1
        Y = int(S[2])-1
        Valid = True
        for J in range(1,8):
            if A[X][J] > 0:
                Valid = False
            if A[J][Y] > 0:
                Valid = False
        if not Valid:
            print('Invalid Position!')
        else:
            A[X][Y] = 1

print(A)
```

Comment: I don't know chess puzzles so I can't really tell what you're going for, but I want to suggest that for a board, you use a (8,8) NumPy array instead of a nested list. It's a bit cleaner because it has fixed shape and dimensions, whereas a list can be changed in ways you won't want. It'll look a bit different, you make one like `A = numpy.zeros((8, 8), dtype = numpy.int8)`, and you index like `A[X, Y]`. `int8` was the smallest data type possible and can take values from -128 to 127. More than enough for the 6 types of pieces, and +/- can indicate which side.

Comment: It seems like a single player chess game and no enemy movement is found, so, from where do you want to detect the diagonal attack?

Comment: @Ghost Ops Yes sir. A single player occupies the entire 8x8 board. The goal is to place as much queen as possible in the condition that they won’t be able to attack each other.

Comment: @BatWanneBe Thank you for your comment. I haven’t learned NumPy yet, but I’ll definitely look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice descriptive way is to not check against `A` but to a set of taken lines. The new queen would for example take "row 3" and "diagonal 5" etc. The diagonals can be numbered by X+Y and X-Y. Check that the four lines the new queen would take aren't already taken, and if they aren't, update `A` and the set of taken lines.

```
A = []
for I in range(0,8):
    A.append([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
taken = set()
for I in range(1,8):
    while True:
        S = input('Enter position'+ str(I) +' : ')
        X = int(S[0])-1
        Y = int(S[2])-1
        take = {('row', X),
                ('column', Y),
                ('diagonal', X+Y),
                ('antidiagonal', X-Y)}
        if take & taken:
            print('Invalid Position!')
        else:
            A[X][Y] = 1
            taken |= take
            break
print(A)
```